# What is the R code for the grouping this dataset

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data set which tells me the returns of a group of dealers. Here I want to get the details of dealers who had returned the most products by the quantity and also their value

dput output:

```
structure(list(Dealer = c("A", "B", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E"), 
    ID = c("Product", "Product", "Product", "Product", "Product", 
    "Product", "Product"), Products = c("X", "Y", "Z", "F", "G", 
    "I", "F"), Quantity = c(52, 98, 398, 6, 27, 10, 20), Value = c(1845, 
    14300, 50148, 14850, 22005, 1720, 49500)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Dealer = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Products = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Quantity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))


Dealer ID   Products   Quantity   Value
del A       Product X   52        1845
del B       Product Y   98        14300
del A       Product Z   398       50148
del D       Product F   6         14850
del C       Product G   27        22005
del E       Product I   10        1720
del E       Product F   20        49500
```

Here **del A** has returned the most followed by **del E**,**del B**.

Thanks

Comment: So group by `Dealer` take `sum` and `arrange`? `df %>%
  group_by(Dealer) %>%
  summarise(Quantity = sum(Quantity), 
            Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Quantity))`

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get the best answer from the community, show us what you have tried already. This site does not provide solutions, but solves problems other developers encounter - i.e. a code snippet not working, available solutions not efficient enough, etc.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you so much for taking your time and replying to my query

Comment: @nya I know, but I am new to this. I'll definitely try to improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tapply` and then sort or filter the resulting array according to your preference.

```r
> df <- read.csv('data.csv')
> df
  Dealer.ID  Products Quantity Value
1     del A Product X       52  1845
2     del B Product Y       98 14300
3     del A Product Z      398 50148
4     del D Product F        6 14850
5     del C Product G       27 22005
6     del E Product I       10  1720
7     del E Product F       20 49500
> v <- tapply(df$Quantity, df$Dealer.ID, FUN=sum)
> v
del A del B del C del D del E 
  450    98    27     6    30
> sort(v, decreasing=T)
del A del B del E del C del D 
  450    98    30    27     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you transform your data set (**df**) into a **data.table** (from the *data.table* library).
When you do, for instance:

```r
> library(data.table)
> df = as.data.table(df)
> new.df = df[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=Dealer,.SDcols=c("Quantity","Value")]
> new.df
   Dealer Quantity Value
1:  del A      450 51993
2:  del B       98 14300
3:  del D        6 14850
4:  del C       27 22005
5:  del E       30 51220
```

If you want it sort out by "Quantity" do:

```r
> new.df[order(-Quantity)]
   Dealer Quantity Value
1:  del A      450 51993
2:  del B       98 14300
3:  del E       30 51220
4:  del C       27 22005
5:  del D        6 14850
```

which gives you your desired answer (I guess).
Bear in mind that the columns "Quantity" and "Value" must be of class **numeric**.